# React - how to determine if component is stateless/functional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have functional/stateless component and component which inherited from `React.Component`:

```
const Component1 = () => (<span>Hello</span>)

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<span>Hello</span>)
  }
}
```

How can I determine if component is stateless or not? Is there any official way?

```
isStateless(Component1) // true
isStateless(Component2) // false
```

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: @JuanMendes I can set `ref` prop using `React.createElement` function but functional components cannot have refs. At the time I don't know component type (it is dynamic).

Comment: You want to set refs on a component outside of itself?

Comment: Your question feels like "how to know if there is a bug in a function?"

Comment: @JuanMendes you will get warning when you try: `createElement(() => null, { ref: 'myRef' })`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can check it's prototype, for example:

```
function isStateless(Component) {
    return !Component.prototype.render;
}
```

Comment: Correct the function, it has a bug.
See my answer below.

Comment: do check if its a string should be okay.

Comment: This won't work if `render` is instance method, `render = () => ...`.

Comment: `Component` may not have a `prototype`

Answer (score 13):

Class components are inherently stateful, but with the introduction of React hooks functional components are no longer called stateless because they can be stateful, too.

`isReactComponent` special property exists on `React.Component` since React 0.14. This allows to determine whether a component is class component.

```
function isFunctionalComponent(Component) {
  return (
    typeof Component === 'function' // can be various things
    && !(
      Component.prototype // native arrows don't have prototypes
      && Component.prototype.isReactComponent // special property
    )
  );
}

function isClassComponent(Component) {
  return !!(
    typeof Component === 'function'
    && Component.prototype
    && Component.prototype.isReactComponent
  );
}
```

Similar checks are performed in React code base.

Since components can be various things like context `Provider` or `Consumer`, `isFunctionalComponent(Component)` may not be equal to `!isClassComponent(Component)`.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what does one call "stateless".
If by stateless one means "can't have a `ref`" then it's:

```
function isStateless(Component) {
  return typeof Component !== 'string' && !Component.prototype.render
}
```

Update: there's also a new `PropTypes.elementType` type for React components (not "elements").

Comment: who has down vote this answer? this is correct one. because a string sometimes can be render with react.

Comment: Yes, one can assign `ref` to a string component (like "div") and it will be valid, while stateless components cannot have `ref`s because they don't have a DOM node of their own. I guess it depends on how one defines "stateless".

Comment: and dont forget fragment and return array as children in react 16 later

Comment: Actually, `Component` is not an `Element` so a component can't be neither an array nor a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me now (React 16.12.0) to test if a component was a function.
(I needed it for dealing with whether I needed to wrap a component with `React.forwardRef` to avoid problems like https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup/issues/137)

```
    (typeof component === "object" && typeof component.type === "function")
```